# Releasing GCHandles on application exit

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

say I have

```
var hGCFile = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer, GCHandleType.Pinned)
```

And I P/Invoke some unmanaged function with

```
SaveStream(hGCFile.AddrOfPinnedObject())
```

Further, suppose the above function saves the buffer address and uses it throughout my application's lifetime.

In such a case, is there a benefit to calling

```
hGCFile.Free()
```

Before shutting down my application? It's just that I'd guess the CLR would do it anyway upon appdomain teardown

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the finalizer for *buffer* will never run.  Hard to see how that could matter, you wouldn't be able to pin it if it was an object with anything interesting inside.

It is *very* unfriendly to the garbage collector, it has to constantly work around the obstacle and can't compact the heap well enough to give your app the best use of the CPU cache.  Especially bad if it is in gen #0, it will be.

There is very rarely a good reason to give the GC such a hard time, just allocate *real* unmovable memory.  Use Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem() and Marshal.StructureToPtr() (if and where needed).  Now you *do* care about releasing that memory when unloading the AppDomain doesn't also terminate the process.  That IntPtr will be gonzo.

But do note that the lifetime of the AppDomain is *not* in any way associated with the lifetime of unmanaged code.  That DLL you loaded will not be unloaded along with the AppDomain.  It isn't clear from your question whether this unmanaged code could still use that buffer, it could since it is still there.  If it does, it is *really* important that you don't use pinned memory.

Comment: Thank you, this is some very sound advice. Also very enlightening technically.

Comment: How about FixedAddressValueTypeAttribute? Will that allocate unmovable memory to begin with as well ?

Comment: First I heard of it, looks like a C++/CLI attribute.  Meh, you can't do anything useful with a value type value.

Comment: Yeah, it's some kind of phantom attribute, and you're probably right. Thanks again !

Answer (score 2):

**When the `AppDomain` is unloaded, it's guaranteed that all memory allocated by the `AppDomain` is released.**

Read a few days ago that they actually got the memory consumption down to 12 bytes between before the `AppDomain` was created and after it was unloaded :).

Comment: +1 Thanks for that! Interestingly, I can't find any finalizer for GCHandle using Reflector - what am I missing ?

Comment: *Very* nice showing on this week's user leagues.  My compliments.  And enjoying reading your contributions, great job.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Thank you. Still a few hundred point below Nick Craver though :S.

Comment: @ohadsc - Got this information from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx.

Comment: @Pieter I am still puzzled - The same page states "Object.Finalize does nothing by default. It must be overridden by a derived class". As far as I can see, neither ValueType nor GCHandle override it  (Again, Reflector)

Comment: @ohadsc - Sorry, stupid, I see now that the link is to Object.Finalize. I've updated the answer. The rest still stands though.

Comment: No worries, you've still been a great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Once your application exits, you need to make sure all **unmanaged** resources are released. `GCHandle` deals with the **managed** resource (CLR heap) so no action is required.

Not releasing a pinned `GCHandle` will cause the GC not being able to move the objects and compress the used memory in heap. So this will be all managed memory and if app is exiting, it does not matter anymore.